Fastlane deliver init downloads metadata from iOS instead of macOS
I'm working on a Flutter app targeting, among others, iOS and macOS.
I want to set up Fastlane for the macOS version of my app, so here is what I did in a terminal:

go to the macOS folder
run sudo fastlane init (and choose Manual setup)

Then I updated the fastlane/Appfile file with the correct info (app_identifier, apple_id, its_team_id and team_id) which are the same as the iOS version.
And in order to get all the metadata locally, including the screenshots, I run:
sudo fastlane deliver init --use_live_version true

But for some reason, I got the screenshots of the iOS version of my app, instead of the macOS ones.
What should I check or fix to get the macOS metadata?
Thanks.

Here is the right command to get the correct metadata for macOS:
sudo fastlane deliver init --platform=osx --use_live_version true

